# How can we show value of a custom field inside Show-ListView

Tags: powershell-extensions

We would like to show custom data such as custom string(" Test Case 1","Test case 2"). All these data do not inside any items in Sitecore. It is just a string in powershell script and would like to show in `Show-ListView`.

We would like to add one column inside `Show-ListView` and show data under this column.

Is this possible? Kindly assist someone on this.

Comment: Have you reviewed the documentation? What have you tried?

Comment: Yes I have reviewed the document and I have tried with property and ViewName

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1. Using PSCustomObject in array**

```
$list = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
```

in for each loop assign value to info object and then add it to list

```
$info = [PSCustomObject]@{
                            "data1"="test 1"
                            "data2" = "test data 2"
                        }
                    [void]$list.Add($info)
```

then show it finally

```
$list | Show-ListView
```

**2. Using Class, example given below:**

```
class Topics {
    [string]$TopicId
    [string]$TopicPath
    [string]$TopicName
}
```

create its array object

```
[Topics[]]$AllTopics = @()
```

assign values to it

```
$topicfolders|get-childitem |foreach-object{
    $topic=       [Topics]@{
           TopicId =  $_.Id
           TopicPath= $_.fullpath
           TopicName =  $_.name
        
    }
            $AllTopics =[Array] $AllTopics +  $topic
}
#then show $AllTopics
```

**3. Directly assign value to psobject and show that**

```
$customItem = [pscustomobject]@{
    "ID"=$Item.ID
    "Icon"=$Item.__Icon
    "DisplayName"=$Item.DisplayName
    "ItemPath"=$Item.ItemPath
    "Version"=$Item.Version
    "Language"=$Item.Language
    "__Updated"=$Item.__Updated
    "__Updated by"=$Item."__Updated by"
}

$customItem | Show-ListView
```

**4.using Expression of show-listview**, either give your value in it or create a function and use that to get values.

Comment: I have resolved it by adding [PSCustomObject]. Only change is here `$info = [PSCustomObject]@{
                            data1="test 1"
                            data2 = "test data 2"
                        } 
$info | Show-ListView`

Comment: Great, please accept comment as answer if that helped.